# "There is a woman with a snapper."

Tags: nouns, slang, north-american-english

So far, I haven't found a clue to this use of the word "snapper" (1851) to describe an energetic, irrepressibly attractive woman at any of the 19th century slang websites so far.

Here is part of the paragraph in which the word appears, in a letter (dated August 8, 1850) from Evert Duyckinck to his wife Margaret Duyckinck, reproduced in Steven Olsen-Smith, [*Melville in His Own Time*](https://books.google.com/books?id=b1TpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q&f=false) (2015):

> We passed on among the 7000 Shaker acres by the immaculate yellow houses, glazed like a pail, the red barns and the bricky natives, by well cultivated fields to the Hancock village where we saw the huge barn & where Mrs Morewood driving a pair of horses with three ladies had come on to meet us—There's a woman with a snapper. She is to be the owner of this house next year & I must tell you more about her—

What is its origin and what would the man who used the word and the man who read the sentence visualize when using the word?

Comment: Unless you feel you're not getting enough spam e-mail, never post your e-mail address in public on the internet.  I've removed it from the post.

Comment: The phrase “There is a woman with a snapper" does not describe a woman *as* a snapper. But that she *is with one*. She could be, for example, on a dock or pier, holding a fishing pole in one hand and a snapper (a type of fish) in another.  Please tell us where you found this sentence and [edit] your question to include the larger context in which it was found. It would also be helpful if you told us if you'd seen this word more than once, or more generally why you believe it to be common in 19th C speech or writing, or idiomatic, etc.

Comment: It is not necessarily slang at all. Fish, anyone? Sounds like a painting "Woman with Snapper".

Comment: [Steven Olsen-Smith, "Melville in His Own Time", from a letter by E. A. Duyckinck to his wife;August 8, 1850](https://books.google.com/books?id=b1TpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q&f=false) : "We passed on among the 7000 Shaker acres by the immaculate yellow houses, glazed like a pail, the red barns and the bricky natives, by well cultivated fields to the Hancock village where we saw the huge barn & where Mrs Morewood driving a pair of horses with three ladies had come on to meet us -- There's a woman with a snapper. She is to be the owner of this house next year & I must tell you more about her."

Comment: I guess they didn’t have [these](https://www.snapper.com/content/dam/Product%20Catalog/Snapper/en/ridinglawnmowers/7800952-02_SNP_RE210_15.5-33_LF-low.jpg) in the 1850s...   I’m voting for @SvenYargs’s whip suggestion.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that the shakers practiced sexual equality. It would have been a remarkable sight to see a woman driving a team (I presume pulling a wagon) elsewhere in the eastern US at this time. As pacifists, they wouldn't have used horse whips. While snappers could be added to horse whips, I think this refers to something akin to a riding crop that was only a noise maker. Oh, and the barn is [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Round_Stone_Barn%2C_Hancock_Shaker_Village_MA.jpg/250px-Round_Stone_Barn%2C_Hancock_Shaker_Village_MA.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

Mitford Mathews, *A Dictionary of Americanisms on Historical Principles* (1951), offers this entry for the word *snapper*:

> **snapper,** *n.* **1.** = **snapping turtle**. [Citations from 1796 forward omitted.] ... **2.** A cracker at the end of a whip. Usu. transf. in the sense of a word or phrase giving a smart or pointed finish to something. [First three cited examples:] **1835** Hoffman, *Winter in West* I. 179 *Jim* cracked his snapper. **1857** Holland *Bay Path* xiv, You'd a said twenty lashes ... and Mr. Moxon would 'a said twenty Amens on the end on 'em for a snapper. **1895** Mark Twain *How to Tell a Story* 226 (R.) A humorous story finishes with a nub, point, snapper, or whatever you like to call it.

In definition 2, the "cracker" refers (I believe) to a bit of thong attached to the end of the whip to give it (when used properly) an extra-loud cracking sound. I have seen and used bullwhips that have this extra piece of thong on them, but I haven't heard them called "crackers" (or "snappers").

The citation from 1835 uses *snapper* in its literal sense, and could very well be taken to refer to the entire whip; the two later citations use *snapper* figuratively.

The word appears in its literal sense in Philip Paxton, [*A Stray Yankee in Texas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LjceAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA273&dq=%22a+snapper%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT4IuK3bXcAhXjyVQKHdDDB-YQ6AEIRzAF#v=onepage&q=%22a%20snapper%22&f=false) (1853), in the context of a hostile interaction between the Yankee (Green) and a mule (Brandy):

> GREEN. There, take that (attempting an application of the whip, and only succeeding in getting a smart rap with the **snapper** upon his cheek). Rot these darn fool whips!—as long as the moral law'n the ten commandments with the hull book a Revelation for a **snapper**.
>
> After various attempts, Green began, as he said, "to get the hang of the thing," and then commenced a race around the lot, the Yankee cracking away at the mule and getting rather the larger share of the lash himself, until he finally cornered his antagonist in a kind of cul-de-sac, formed by the junction of the fence and stable at a very acute angle.

Evidently, in the sentence "There's a woman with a snapper," the *snapper* is a whip, which makes sense given that the woman in question (Mrs. Morewood) is described as "driving a pair of horses."

Comment: The (paywalled) [OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183018?rskey=7tCmsB&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) has this as sense 1. e.: “*U.S.* A cracker on the end of a whip-lash. Also *fig.,* a sharp or caustic remark.” This entry has not been updated for the OED3 yet. Its earliest citation is “1817   J. Sansom Sk. Lower Canada 15   One had proposed to put *a snapper* on the driver's whip.”

Comment: So perhaps it meant something like today's "there's a woman with a lead foot"?

Comment: @1006a: Something like that. I read it as implying, "Now _there's_ a formidable woman."

Comment: *A Dictionary of Americanisms on Historical Principles* - nice - is this online? I saw it for sale used for $550! Maybe SE could host OED and this for us!

Comment: does explain the term *cracker* though too.

Comment: @lbf: I bought my copy several years ago on eBay for $50, but it usually fetches a higher price.  [Volume 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=l29XAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Dictionary+of+Americanisms+on+Historical+Principles%22&dq=%22Dictionary+of+Americanisms+on+Historical+Principles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPhPblmrbcAhVM-lQKHeE0DSMQ6AEIKTAA) of the two-volume edition is available through Google Books in snippet view only, which severely limits its utility, but is better than nothing (unless you're looking for a word that's in Volume 2).

Comment: @SvenYarg: If all you have is volume 1, the word you're looking for will always be in volume 2.

Answer (score 3):

A "snapper" is an Irish slang word for **baby**. From Collins English Dictionary:

> **snapper** (ˈsnæpə)
>   6. *informal Irish* a baby

The word is still in use today in Ireland, and also widely understood in Great Britain. See e.g. the 1990 Roddy Doyle novel [The Snapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Snapper_(novel)), about the pregnancy of a young unmarried woman, or its 1993 Stephen Frears [film adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Snapper_(film)).

It seems obvious that "a woman with a snapper" would simply be a woman with a baby or small child, rather than a woman carrying a fish or whip.

The word "snapper" has been in use in Ireland and Britian for centuries, but because it has several meanings, I haven't been able to find a source for it being used specifically for a baby in the mid-nineteenth century. It would of course not be unusual for an Irish word to have entered American English at that time.

Comment: I haven't read Doyle's novel, but the film is excellent. According to Jonathon Green, _Chambers Slang Dictionary_ (2008), _snapper_ in the Irish sense of "a baby, a small child" comes from _breadsnapper_ and dates only to the 1950s. As for _breadsnapper_ itself, Green says that it dates to the late 19th century, means "lit. 'a child who can eat their weight in groceries'," and  originated as "_Scot., Glasgow/Irish/US_." Google Books searches for _breadsnapper_, _bread-snapper_, and _bread snapper_ for the period 1800–1911, however, don't return any matches.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks. I've removed the mention of "whippersnapper", because that was obviously a wrong assumption.